# Export Data Bigquery for tables bigger than 1GB

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to export a Bigquery table that is bigger than 1GB using gcp lib for go. I'm following the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data?hl=pt-br#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files

But when I run a for each in the select query it only creates files from one export_id.

What I did was create a table

```
    CREATE TABLE ` + "`" + dstTableName + "`" + `
    PARTITION BY RANGE_BUCKET(export_id, GENERATE_ARRAY(0, @nbr, 1))
    CLUSTER BY export_id
    AS (
    SELECT *, CAST(FLOOR(@nbr*RAND()) AS INT64) AS export_id
    FROM ` + "`" + originalTable + "`" + `
    );
```

And after that I did a for each for each export_id. If I set overwrite for false it complains and ask for overwrite.

`googleapi: Error 400: overwrite option is not specified and destination is not empty., invalid`

That's the code

```
for i := int64(0); i < nbrPartition; i++ {
    println("starting partition: ", i)
    newQuery := b.c.Query(`
        EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
        uri=@uri,
        format='CSV',
        header=true,
        overwrite=true,
        field_delimiter=';'
        ) AS
        SELECT * 
        FROM ` + "`" + dstTableName + "`" + `
        WHERE export_id = @nbr;
    `)

    newQuery.Parameters = []bigquery.QueryParameter{
        {
            Name:  "uri",
            Value: fmt.Sprintf("gs://%s/wbl_test/%s_*_.csv", b.config.ProjectId, fileName),
        },
        {
            Name:  "nbr",
            Value: i,
        },
    }

    job, err := newQuery.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := status.Err(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Looking the files it only creates the last export_id

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: I changed the way to export. I started exporting using the bigquery go lib and it worked. But using the SQL didn't work.